# VBA web-scraping trigger a filter with a search term

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

With VBA, I am trying to programmatically enter a search term at https://data.seattle.gov/Permitting/Electrical-Permits-Current/raim-ay5x into an input element. Simply entering ieInput.value= "RENEWABLE ENERGY" then ieInput.click does not trigger the filter.

Any ideas?

My test code:

Sub EnterSearchTerm()

```
Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
If ieApp Is Nothing Then Set ieApp = New InternetExplorerMedium

ieApp.navigate "https://data.seattle.gov/Permitting/Electrical-Permits-Current/raim-ay5x"
ieApp.Visible = True
While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
While ieApp.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents:  Wend

Dim ieInput As HTMLInputElement
Set ieInput = ieApp.document.getElementsByClassName("searchField textPrompt prompt")(0)
ieInput.Value = "RENEWABLE ENERGY"
ieInput.Click
```

End Sub

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is no submit button on the form, and the input field is no reason to click its not a clickable field, its being filtered with a javascript event when the user hits enter, so here is two solutions you can try.

1) try to figure out which javascript event is being fired when you click enter, and when you find the function name, just add in your vba this line

```
    ie.Document.all.Item 
Call ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript("ENTER HERE THE JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION NAME()", "JavaScript") 
.submit
```

2) this method might not be the best to do because it will only work if your ie is your current window and is active window, but if its the case,  you can do the following.

```
Application.SendKeys "~"
```

Comment: Looks like all key entries pass through a JQuery defined object.method f.event including entering each letter of the search term. For now, I will just code my app to have the user manually enter the search term.